# Mapping My Documents to Users area

Tags: active-directory, automation, documents

I am looking to automate a process that we have to carry out, when building a PC for a user we have to map their my documents to their area on our server is there a way to automate this process? I have tried setting up a group policy in AD users>policies>windows settings>folder redirection and then to documents and setting up a basic policy and inputting the relevant path. I did also create a Vbscript to rewrite the documents.library-ms file on the computers both have failed, except the GP worked on windows 8 machines and not windows 7
Does anyone know how we could map my documents autonomously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group Policy is the way to go. Why it fails on your Windows 7 box I can't say, but you can use (run) rsop.msc to troubleshoot GP issues from the client.

Comment: Did a full strip down of the GPO's and the way in which we setup user's the issue was in AD when creating a user's homeshare they are not given ownership of the area and the user has to have ownership of an area to map to it using a GPO

Comment: MS has documented pretty much everything around how to set up folder redirection, and the required permissions on the file share. Here, for example:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649078.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think Roaming User Profiles is what you are after.

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738596%28v=ws.10%29.aspx